# A complete eigenvector basis for the restricted operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a (not necessarily bounded) selfadjoint linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$ and let $M$ be a closed subspace such that $X(M) \subset M$.

> Suppose that $X$ admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors. Does it follow that $X|_M$ admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors too?

I think that the answer is 'yes' if $X$ commutes with the orthoprojection of range $M$:

$$PX \subset XP,$$

but I don't know what happens without this hypothesis. What do you think?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems to me that the hypothesis that $PX\subseteq XP$ should always hold, but I don't have proof.  What do you think?

Comment: @Jonas: Motivated by your comment I started a search. Looks like you're right, at least for *bounded* $X$. Indeed, as I see in Kubrulsky's book [link](http://books.google.it/books?id=g-UFYTO8SbMC&lpg=PA442&ots=Y7voAWfWrA&dq=reducing%20subspace&hl=it&pg=PA390#v=onepage&q&f=false), Proposition 5.74, if $X$ is bounded then $M$ *reduces* $X$ (which is the same as $PX=XP$, if I'm not mistaken) iff $X(M)\subset M$ and $X^\star(M)\subset M$. For bounded selfadjoint operators, then, reducing subspaces and invariant subspaces are the same thing.

Comment: Errata corrige: In previous comment I mistakenly wrote "Kubrulsky" instead of the correct "Kubrusly".

Comment: I'm a little confused about the unbounded case.  Then do you require that $M\subseteq D(X)$ (so that $M$ being _closed_ seems quite a strong condition) or merely that $X( M\cap D(X)) \subseteq M$??

Comment: @MatthewDaws: I had in mind $M \subset D(X)$. With only $X(M \cap D(X))\subset M$ we should add some density hypothesis, I think (for example $X(M \cap D(X))$ may be $\{0\}$ or something like that). However, it is the bounded case that interests me the most.

Comment: Giuseppe: Yes, I was motivated by knowing it is true in the bounded case.  In any case, note that $PXP=XP$.  If $X$ is bounded, taking adjoints of the last equation shows that $PX=PXP=XP$.  It is just that with unbounded operators, I am not sure how much of that carries through.  If $A$ and $B$ are densely defined operators, then (I think) $B^*A^*\subseteq (AB)^*$, and I was thinking that this could be used to show that $PX\subseteq XP$ still holds.  I don't plan to try to check the details soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the details of Jonas's suggestion.  Let $X$ be self-adjoint with dense domain $D(X)$, and let $M$ be a closed subspace with $M\subseteq D(X)$ and $X(M)\subseteq M$.  Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto $M$.  Then $D(PX) = D(X)$ while $D(XP)=H$ as $P$ has range $M\subseteq D(X)$.  For $\xi\in H$, let $\xi_0=P(\xi), \xi_1=\xi-P(\xi)$, and let $\eta\in D(X)$.  Then $$ (PX\eta|\xi) = (PX\eta|\xi_0) + (PX\eta|\xi_1) = (PX\eta|\xi_0)
= (X\eta|P\xi_0) = (X\eta|\xi_0) $$
as $PX\eta\in M$ and $\xi_1\in M^\perp$.  As $\xi_0\in M\subseteq D(X)$ and $X$ is self-adjoint,
$$ (X\eta|\xi_0) = (\eta|X\xi_0) = (\eta|PX\xi_0) = (P\eta|X\xi_0) = (XP\eta|\xi_0), $$
as $X\xi_0 \in X(M) \subseteq M$.  Similarly, $(XP\eta|\xi_1) = 0$ as $XP\eta \in X(M) \subseteq M$ and $\xi_1\in M^\perp$.   As $\xi$ was arbitrary, this shows that $XP\eta=PX\eta$.  So we've shown that
$$ D(PX) \subseteq D(XP), PX\eta=XP\eta \ (\eta\in D(X)) \implies
PX \subseteq XP. $$

As the OP claimed, this is enough.  If $e$ is an eigenvector of $X$ then $PXe = P\lambda e = \lambda Pe$, and by the above, this also is equal to $XPe$.  So $Pe\in M$ is an eigenvector for $X$ (unless it's zero!)  As the original collection of eigenvectors has desne linear span, so does the projection onto $M$.